# Help Proving that Set Invariant for a Dynamical System.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm practicing for an upcoming test, and this one has been giving me some problems.

Suppose we have

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x = x^2 + 2y - 4 \\
\dot y = -2xy
\end{cases}.
$$
Let $R = \{(x,y) : |x| \leq 2,\, 0 \leq y \leq 4 - x^2\}$. I'm to prove this is invariant, i.e., if $x_0 \in R$, then
$$
\Phi(t, x_0) \in R, \hspace{1em} \forall t\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
So far, I have $y = 0$ stays on $\{(x,0) : |x| \leq 2\}$, so the bottom line boundary is invariant. But, I'm having trouble with the boundary of the parabola. If it's invariant, then obviously we are done; but it may just be a trapping region.

Any hints on where to go would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x_0$, and consider the upper parabola near the point $(x_0,4-x_0^2)$.  Differentiating, the vector $(1,-2x_0)$ points tangent to the parabola.

OTOH, your system satisfies (at that point) \begin{align*}
\dot{x}&=x_0^2+2(4-x_0)^2-4=4-x_0^2 \\
\dot{y}&=-2x_0(4-x_0^2)  
\end{align*}  That is, $$(\dot{x},\dot{y})=(4-x_0^2)(1,-2x_0)$$

So the upper parabola is also an invariant curve, tending towards $(2,0)$.

Since both the upper and bottom boundaries are invariant and the system is in continuous time, the region between is invariant too.